# Почему метод containsValue() работает некорректно

Tags: java

```
public class Task6 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        //содержание карты 1  
        Map<String,Integer> m = new HashMap<String,Integer>();  
        m.put("X", 4);  
        m.put("X^2", 5);  
        m.put("X^5", 7);

        //содержание карты 2
        Map<String,Integer> map2 = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        m.put("X", 1);
        m.put("X^2",2);
        m.put("X^5", 4);
        System.out.println(m.containsValue(6));
        System.out.println(map2.containsValue(1));
```

В результате выводит true и false! В чем ошибка?

Comment: отформатируй код, а то половина как код а половина как текст

Comment: такие вопросы решаются при помощи дебаггера :). навскидку у тебя проблема с инициализацией карты `map2`, ты ее просто не инициализируешь

Comment: у меня код выводит два раза false (что и ожидалось). код точно верно скопировали?

Comment: Скомпилировал? нажал на кнопку запуска, получил результат, вручную ничего не компилировал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка до простоты банальна! 
После создания карты map2 значения добавлялись не в map2 а в m!